# Have volume buttons wake phone

Tags: root-access, volume

I'd like my volume buttons to wake my phone when asleep AND change volume when awake. (LOS style)

Want to do that manually (ideally by editing keylayout files/`build.prop`/`settings put...`), don't want to install any button remapper app.

I took inspiration by Cr0wTom 'Xiaomi Mi AI button remapper' and edited my keylayout at `/system/usr/keylayout/gpio-keys.kl` (you can find what's in use with `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`)

```
key 115   VOLUME_UP
key 114   VOLUME_DOWN
key 102   HOME
key 528   FOCUS
key 766   CAMERA
key 689   POWER
```

last line is AI button that I successfully remapped to POWER.

If I change first line with `key 115   VOLUME_UP WAKE` AI button stops working, volume up keeps working as before and doesn't wake the phone.
If I change to `key 115   WAKEUP` AI button works as remapped POWER, volume up button wakes the phone but does not turn volume up anymore.

running root Xiaomi.eu rom A10 on a Mi9